# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2(x-2)^2}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

What substitution is useful for this integral?

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2(x-2)^2}}\mathrm dx$$

Substitutions $u=x^{\frac{2}{3}},u=(x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}},u=(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}$ are not working.

Can't find useful trigonometric substitution.

Comment: What class is this for? Wolfram evaluated the integral for me and it involves a hypergeometric function, so some context on where this problem is coming from would be nice.

Comment: @bburGsamohT  Calculus 2 class, exam paper problem.

Comment: When you ask for a sub, do you need a sub that leads to an elementary solution or simply one that puts the integral into a "nicer form"?

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen I don't think that any substitution could immediately lead to solution, but if you have an idea on that (or to simplify an integral) then suggest it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change variable to 
$$x - \frac12 = \frac32 u \iff u = \frac{2x-1}{3}
\quad\text{ followed by }\quad
(u^2-1)^{1/3} = v \iff u = \sqrt{1+v^3}$$
We have
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2(x-2)^2}}
= \int\frac{dx}{(x^2-x-2)^{2/3}}
= \int\frac{dx}{\left(\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-\frac{9}{4}\right)^{2/3}}\\
= \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{1/3}\int\frac{du}{(u^2-1)^{2/3}}
= \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{1/3}\int\frac{d\sqrt{1+v^3}}{v^2}
= \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2/3}\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{1+v^3}}
$$
Using result from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33500/59379),
the integral becomes

$$\frac{3^{5/12}}{2^{2/3}}
\left.F\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt[3]{\frac49(x+1)(x-2)}}-1\right)\right|\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)
 + \text{constant}$$
where $\displaystyle\;F(\phi|m) = \int_0^\phi \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m(\sin\theta)^2}}\;$
is the [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: Nice answer indeed !

Answer (score 5):

I found an interesting substitution by a bit of trial and error.
$$\begin{align}
x&=\frac{1+3\sin(u)}{2}\\
\therefore dx&=\frac{3\cos(u)}{2}du\\
x+1&=\frac{3+3\sin(u)}{2}&&=\frac{3(1+\sin(u))}{2}\\
x-2&=\frac{3\sin(u)-3}{2}&&=\frac{3(\sin(u)-1)}{2}\\
\therefore (x+1)(x-2)&=\frac{9(\sin^2(u)-1)}{4}&&=-\frac{9\cos^2(u)}{4}
\end{align}$$
Using these leads to this interesting final integral:$$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\int\frac{du}{\cos^{\frac{1}{3}}(u)}$$

Comment: Unfortunately this integral doesn't seem any easier to solve

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this integral is simple enough to show though that no elementary solution for the antiderivative exists. Perhaps the hypergeometric could be represented as a simpler Special Function, but I sincerely doubt this will turn out to be elementary

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Brevan Ellefsen, there is no elementary solution for $$I=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\int\frac{du}{\cos^{\frac{1}{3}}(u)}$$ but there is effectively a solution using hypergeometric function. It seems to be $$I=-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2/3} \cos ^{\frac{2}{3}}(u) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2};\frac{4}{3};\cos ^2(u)\right)$$ where appears the Gaussian (sometimes called ordinary) [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

In terms of $x$, the antiderivative is then $$I=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2(x-2)^2}}\, dx= \sqrt[3]{3(x-2)} \,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{4}{3};\frac{2-x}{3}\right)$$ Back to definitions (and getting rid of Pochhammer symbols), $$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3^{-4 n} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\, \Gamma (3 n)}{n!\, \Gamma (n)\,
   \Gamma \left(n+\frac{4}{3}\right)} (2-x)^n$$

**Edit**

The coefficients in the last expression vary extremely fast ( the first  is $1$, the tenth  is $\approx 1.851\times 10^{-7}$, the hundredth is $\approx 1.025\times 10^{-51}$). For large values of $n$, they are $$\log(c_n)=-n \log (3)-\frac{4}{3} \log (n)+\log
   \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{2 \sqrt{3} \pi
   }\right)-\frac{4}{9 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

> *What substitution is useful for this integral ?*

None. The integrand does not possess any elementary anti-derivative. See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra))

and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more information. However, all *definite* integrals of the following

form: $\displaystyle\int_a^b\Big[(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\Big]^r~dx,$ with $a,b\in\{x_1,x_2,\pm\infty\},$ can be evaluated in terms of the

[beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [$\Gamma$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), assuming, of course, that they converge in the first place. This should

come as no surprise, given the fact that **Mufasa** has already been able to rewrite the original

expression as a [Wallis integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals), whose relation to the aforementioned special functions is well

known. Not to mention the fact that **Claude Leibovici's** [hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) can also be

expressed in terms of the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function). Thus, for $x_{1,2}=\{-1,2\}$ and $r=-\dfrac23,$

we have the following result:

> $$\begin{align}
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Big[(x+1)(x-2)\Big]^{-\tfrac23}~dx
> ~&=~3\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\Big[(x+1)(x-2)\Big]^{-\tfrac23}~dx~=~
> \\\\
> ~&=~3\int_{-1}^2\Big[(x+1)(x-2)\Big]^{-\tfrac23}~dx~=~
> \\\\
> ~&=~3\int_2^\infty\Big[(x+1)(x-2)\Big]^{-\tfrac23}~dx~=~
> \\\\
> ~&=~3\cdot\frac{B\Big(\tfrac13~,~\tfrac16\Big)}{\sqrt[3]{12}}
> \end{align}$$

Comment: Nice answer for sure ! Cheers.