# What is the integral of an inverse square root of a standard cubic formula?

Tags: integration, cubics

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}}dx$$

I know the solution to the integral of an inversed square root of a quadratic equation.

But I am not being able to solve this one and I have searched online to find a solution. Unfortunately I seem to have found nothing.

So help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a simple integral in fact. You can have a look at [this particular one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33412/).

Comment: Thank you, and can it be done? Did anyone try to solve integrals like this before?

Comment: History of mathematics is something I know virtually nothing about, but this looks to me like an elliptic integral. If I’m right, the history goes back at least 200 years, well past Abel.

Comment: That's very interesting. @lubin

Answer (score 2):

As @Lubin wrote in comments, you face elliptic integrals.

The easiest way to handle them is to write
$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+q=a(x-r)(x-s)(x-t)$$ where $(r,s,t)$ are the roots of the cubic equation. 
I let the simplifications to you

If the three roots are different  the antiderivative will write
$$-\frac{2 (x-r)^{3/2} \sqrt{\frac{x-s}{x-r}} \sqrt{\frac{x-t}{x-r}} }{\sqrt{s-
   r} \sqrt{a (x-r) (x-s) (x-t)}}\,\,F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{s-r}}{\sqrt{x-r}}\right)|\frac{r-t}{r-s}\right)$$

If there is a double root $(t=s)$
$$\frac{2 \sqrt{x-r} (x-s) }{\sqrt{r-s} \sqrt{a (x-r)
   (x-s)^2}}\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x-r}}{\sqrt{r-s}}\right)$$
If there is a triple root $(t=s=r)$
$$-\frac{2 (x-r)}{\sqrt{a (x-r)^3}}$$

Comment: My God! Thank you very much. @Claude

Comment: @AYMShahriarRahman. You are welcome ! Did you expect something simple ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Didn't expect something simple actually. Just speechless thinking how someone could derive that. @Claude